# Add a custom variable to query page object

Tags: wp-query, terms

Is there a way to add a custom variable to the queried object?

```
if (is_page()) {
    $q = get_queried_object();
    $term_id = $q->term_id;
}
```

Here's some background on my setup.

I have a page with a custom WP_Query that outputs all posts from a particular taxonomy. I need to save the taxonomy **'term_id'** somewhere so other areas of my code can know which category in the custom loop is currently being displayed.

Right now I am using 'update_post_meta' to store a custom field to the page which holds this value. I don't want to use a custom field though. So I am looking for the best alternate solution.

```
if ($meta_term_id > -1) {
    update_post_meta( get_queried_object()->ID, 'term_id', $meta_term_id);
}

// Build Query
$custom_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

I have looked into add_query_vars but I don't want to add an url param to every page.

```
www.mydomain.com/custom-page/?term_id='38';
```

I'm hoping there is a way to attach data to the page object which will have the term_id I need.

***Update****

I didn't figure out a way to add custom data to the post object like I had hoped but did find a solution to creating custom post meta data but not showing the custom field on the page edit screen. Just need to prepend the post meta data name with an underscore.

```
update_post_meta( get_queried_object()->ID, '_term_id', $meta_term_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated my question with a partial answer to this problem. By adding an underscore '_' before the name of the meta field it allows you to add meta data without it creating an editable custom field on the page edit screen.

```
update_post_meta( get_queried_object()->ID, '_term_id', $meta_term_id);
```